# Using a comma after "but" as done on W4 form

Tags: commas

http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf

The sentence is found on line C, where it says...

> **But,** you may choose to enter “-0-” if you are married and have either a working spouse or more than one job.

Is that correct? And why? Seems rather odd that the government would make such a mistake, no?

Edit - I'm not asking if it's correct or not to put a comma after a conjunction. I'm asking if it's OK to use "But" as a substitute for "However." I'm also not asking if it's "always necessary" to put a comma after conjunctive adverbs like "however." I'm saying this because it's the government that wrote it, and the government, I'd think, would be right in doing so. I just wanted to know if it's "generally" acceptable to do that or if it's an actual mistake.

Comment: Certainly it’s correct: here it’s not a conjunction but rather an adverb meaning *nevertheless* or *however*. Surely the dictionary would tell you that.

Comment: So it's correct? Okay. That was my confusion because it's the GOVERNMENT. Since when does the government make grammar mistakes?

Comment: Presumably, the government uses a different style guide to you. (The one ***I*** use only exists in my head, and it lets me include a comma after the first word in this comment, regardless of what other style guides say! :)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the info--that's exactly what I wanted to know: if it was a style issue or something else. Thanks for the answer!

@tchrist no, it doesn't say so. Do a google search for "define but" and you'll see that as an adverb it's only used as "only."

Comment: Google is not a dictionary; the OED ***is*** a dictionary—and it says **“2.** In a distinct member of a compound sentence (**usually after a semicolon or colon**); or at the beginning of a following sentence. 25. Introducing a statement of the nature of an exception, objection, limitation, or contrast to what has gone before; sometimes, in its weakest form, merely expressing disconnexion, or emphasizing the introduction of a distinct or independent fact, as the minor premiss of a syllogism: However, on the other hand, moreover, yet. In OE. *ac*, Ger. *aber*, L. *autem*.” **General Reference.**

Comment: @FumbleFingers your head must be very heavy.

Comment: @Mitch: It's a lightweight guide. Basically, it just says *If it seems okay to me, it's okay*. I do not carry responsibility for all the world's illiterates on my shoulders.

Comment: @Mitch Sad indeed is the day whose people confuse matters of punctuation  with those of grammar.

Comment: @LucidityofPower 1) The comma after 'but' is a variation that is perfectly acceptable. It may not be the first choice in many style guides or by many editors but is acceptable. 2) Government employees, as well-educated as they might be, are not actual authorities on usage grammar or punctuation. You'd like and expect them to be so, but that don't make it so.

Comment: @FumbleFingers haha. I was also going to ask you if your refrigerator is running.

Comment: Well, thank you all for your effort to answer this question. You've given me all I need to know now!